# For some reason, my Laplacian filter program is not working

Tags: java

So all the methods you see here were given by my instructor. They work just fine, they've been using them for years. I am aware that my code might look too long or inefficient. I intentionally did that because I want to magnify everything, and once I get this thing to work I will shorten it and create a method that calculates the weighted sum.

To test if this code makes changes to the right colors, I assigned redSum to 255, and everything else to 0, and the image produced was pure red. Did the same for green and blue.

I cannot figure out what I'm missing here. Also the weights in the laplacian int array were given.

**The original picture we are supposed to apply the filters to:**
[image: the original picture we are supposed to apply the filters to]

**how the picture is supposed to look life after applying the Laplacian filter**
[image: how the picture is supposed to look life after applying the Laplacian filter]

**the result that I got after applying the filter with my current program**
[image: the result that I got after applying the filter with my current program]

```
public class LaplacianFilter implements Filter
{

  public void filter(PixelImage pi) {

     Pixel[][] data = pi.getData();
     int laplacian [][] = {{-1,-1, -1}, {-1, 8, -1}, {-1, -1, -1}};
     Pixel[][] temp = data;
     for(int row = 1; row < pi.getHeight() - 1; row++)
     {
         for(int col = 1; col < pi.getWidth() - 1; col++)
         {

            int redSum =  laplacian[0][0]*data[row-1][col-1].red + laplacian[0][1]*data[row-1][col+0].red + laplacian[0][2]*data[row-1][col+1].red + 
                          laplacian[1][0]*data[row+0][col-1].red + laplacian[1][1]*data[row+0][col+0].red + laplacian[1][2]*data[row+0][col+1].red + 
                          laplacian[2][0]*data[row+1][col-1].red + laplacian[2][1]*data[row+1][col+0].red + laplacian[2][2]*data[row+1][col+1].red;

            int greenSum = laplacian[0][0]*data[row-1][col-1].green + laplacian[0][1]*data[row-1][col+0].green + laplacian[0][2]*data[row-1][col+1].green + 
                           laplacian[1][0]*data[row+0][col-1].green + laplacian[1][1]*data[row+0][col+0].green + laplacian[1][2]*data[row+0][col+1].green + 
                           laplacian[2][0]*data[row+1][col-1].green + laplacian[2][1]*data[row+1][col+0].green + laplacian[2][2]*data[row+1][col+1].green;

            int blueSum = laplacian[0][0]*data[row-1][col-1].blue + laplacian[0][1]*data[row-1][col+0].blue + laplacian[0][2]*data[row-1][col+1].blue + 
                          laplacian[1][0]*data[row+0][col-1].blue + laplacian[1][1]*data[row+0][col+0].blue + laplacian[1][2]*data[row+0][col+1].blue + 
                          laplacian[2][0]*data[row+1][col-1].blue + laplacian[2][1]*data[row+1][col+0].blue + laplacian[2][2]*data[row+1][col+1].blue;

             redSum = Math.min(255, Math.max(0, redSum));
             greenSum = Math.min(255, Math.max(0, greenSum));
             blueSum = Math.min(255, Math.max(0, blueSum));

             temp[row][col].red = redSum;
             temp[row][col].green = greenSum;
             temp[row][col].blue = blueSum;

         }
     }
     pi.setData(temp);
  }
}
```

Comment: I see the result image has only black/white/grey -- have you tried converting to greyscale (where R=G=B)?  By the looks of that image, you can probably just sum R+B+G, and any result that's over 255 should just be set to 0 -- that way your transform is only making "subtle" details visible.

Comment: @Gus the standard way to transform to grayscale is with weighting, e.g. `0.33*r + 0.56*b + 0.11*b`, or something like that. I've trawled those weightings from my distant memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`temp` and `data` are pointing to the same memory location thus `data` is being overwritten in each iteration.

```
temp[row][col].red = redSum;
temp[row][col].green = greenSum;
temp[row][col].blue = blueSum;
```

Ininitialize temp to its own array:

```
Pixel[][] temp = new Pixel[data.length][data[0].length];
```

Since you are iterating from 1 to `width/height - 1` all the "corners" of temp, e.g. `temp[0][0]` will be `null` so you will need to fill them up before you call `pi.setData(temp);`

```
int lastRow = temp.length - 1;
int lastCol = temp[0].length - 1;
temp[0] = data[0];
temp[lastRow] = data[lastRow];

for(int i = 1; i < lastRow; ++i) {
    temp[i][0] = data[i][0];
    temp[i][lastCol] = data[i][lastCol];
}
pt.setData(temp);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I forgot to even consider this. But with the new modifications, the program is taking a very long time to apply the filter. Any thoughts on why is that happenning?

Comment: @510NH "why is that happening" because of `Pixel[][] temp = data;`.

Comment: @510NH is it producing the right output, just taking a long time? Or just taking forever and not finishing?

Comment: @AndyTurner I removed that part and replaced it with the line StaticBeagle provided. It's been 5 minutes and the new image hasn't been computed yet.

Comment: @StaticBeagle taking forever and not finishing

Comment: @510NH It's hard to diagnose what might be the cause for things to take so long since we are not doing anything special, just writing to another buffer. I would expect it to take about the same time as before. One thing to check for is that since `row` and `col` go from 1 to `length - 1`, all the "borders" of `temp` e.g `temp[0][0]` will contain `null` values so try filling those up with the original data

Comment: @StaticBeagle I got it to work! took less than a second. Here's what I did: instead of Pixel[][] temp = new Pixel[data.length][data[0].length];          I used Pixel[][] temp = pi.getData();     which is the same method used to get the pixels from the picture into the data array of pixels, except now it's referring to different memory location.

Comment: @StaticBeagle  I'm not sure on the differences between your suggested method of cloning the 2d array of pixels vs what I just did.

Comment: @510NH nice. Great idea, that probably returns a brand new clone of the image data without the `null` corners. If I had to take a guess on what was causing it to take so long, I'll bet on the `nulls` that were left in the "corners" of temp. I've updated my answer to explain this a bit more. Maybe `setData(...)` doesn't like nulls. Anyways I'm glad you got your issue resolved and glad I could help.